# How to handle different entities with same structure - linq queries essentially the same

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two different entities (database first) that have the exact same structure but different naming conventions. Is there a way I can simplify the seemingly duplicated code that comes from querying them (ie in `DoWorkWithSimilar`)?

I have tried doing something with generics but am having troubles getting the linq queries to work. Also I try to shy away from generics when possible because I like to be more explicit. Nevertheless, the `DoWorkWithSimilar` methods in the two respective classes are extremely similar. I am trying to think of a better way to streamline these two classes (`DoWorkSimilarOne` and `DoWorkSimilarTwo`) however, due to my constraint on the structure of the underlying classes... I am struggling. Is there no better way?

```
 public class DoWorkSimilarOne : IDoWork
    {
        public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public DoWorkSimilarOne(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
        {
           unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
        }
        public IEnumerable<int> DoWorkWithSimilar(IEnumerable<int> otherIds)
        {

            IEnumerable<int> similarOneIds = unitOfWork.OtherSimilarOnes
                .Where(x => otherIds.Contains(x.Other.OtherId))
                .SelectMany(x => x.SimilarOnes)
                .Select(x => x.SimilarOneId).ToList();
            return similarOneIds;
        }

    }

    public class DoWorkSimilarTwo : IDoWork
    {
        public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public DoWorkSimilarTwo(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
        {
           unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> DoWorkWithSimilar(IEnumerable<int> otherIds)
        {

            IEnumerable<int> similarTwoIds = unitOfWork.OtherSimilarTwos
                .Where(x => otherIds.Contains(x.Other.OtherId))
                .SelectMany(x => x.SimilarTwos)
                .Select(x => x.SimilarTwoId).ToList();
            return similarTwoIds;
        }

    }

    public class SimilarOne
    {
        public int SimilarOneId { get; set; }
        public OtherSimilarOnes OtherSimilarOne { get; set; }
    }

    public class SimilarTwo
    {
        public int SimilarTwoId { get; set; }
        public OtherSimilarTwos OtherSimilarTwo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Other
    {
        public int OtherId { get; set; }
    }

    public class OtherSimilarOnes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Other Other { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SimilarOne> SimilarOnes { get; set; }
    }

    public class OtherSimilarTwos
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Other Other { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SimilarTwo> SimilarTwos { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDoWork
    {
        IEnumerable<int> DoWorkWithSimilar(IEnumerable<int> otherIds);
    }
```

Comment: Make an interface, and have your service logic operate on the interface instead of the acutal entity

Comment: ...or pass in selector lambdas. But three of them gets pretty unweildy.

Comment: Are those classes "somewhat" similar or _exactly_ the same?

Comment: @Evk similar other than the naming and that they resemble two different tables with different data. Nevertheless, the relationship the parent table is exactly the same and how I need to retrieve that data is exactly the same.

Comment: But you can rename entity properties (not columns) since you are using database first and make them exactly the same (that is - with the same set of properties with same types)?

Comment: @Evk Ohh... ya you're right. Let me check this out. But I will still have two completely different instances. Would I then use a generic for the linq query? I am still confused how that would work

Comment: I'd not use generics here but just create interface with all properties of both entities (which have the same name and type now). Then, because database first entities are partial, you just do `public partial class FirstEntity: IMyInterface {}` and `public partial class SecondEntity: IMyInterface {}`. Nothing more, since both entities already implement that interface.

Comment: @Evk Ok I get it. Makes sense - then I can use DI to designate which instance is what. Cool. Thank you.

Comment: Even without DI you can rewrite your method as `DoWorkWithSimilar(IQueryable<IMyInterface> query, IEnumerable<int> otherIds)` and then reuse it for both sets.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you just need to make your method generic and add some base classes, right?

```
public abstract class ObjectWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectThatRelates<T> : ObjectWithId
    where T : ObjectWithId
{
    public int OtherId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Similar { get; set; }
}

public class Object1 : ObjectWithId
{
    public ObjectThatRelates<Object1> { get; set; }
}

public class Object2 : ObjectWithId
{
    public ObjectThatRelates<Object2> { get; set; }
}
```

Then your methods become:

```
public IEnumerable<int> DoWorkWithSimilar<T>(IEnumerable<int> otherIds)
{
    IEnumerable<int> similarOneIds = unitOfWork.ObjectThatRelates<T>
        .Where(x => otherIds.Contains(x.OtherId))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Similar)
        .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
     return similarOneIds;
}
```

Of course, your definition of `IUnitOfWork` will have to change so that it can return either `ObjectThatRelates<Object1>` or `ObjectThatRelates<Object2>` but this should allow you to avoid duplication of effort.

Comment: I understand how this is working but I am constrained by a database first set up... I cant change the classes.

Comment: I guess with partial classes I could.